# Does ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION provide latitude and longitude information?

Tags: android

I want to get user's latitude and longitude information.
Can ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION provide?
**"Allows an app to access precise location from location sources such as GPS, cell towers, and Wi-Fi."**

So what type of data does "GPS" provide?
I just want user's **latitude and longitude** information, please inform me how to implement it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you can probably get this from reading the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) is the class which provides access to the system location services.

For using LocationManager you need either of two permissions

> ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` provides approximate location information since it does not have access to GPS ,it  uses cell towers and Wi-Fi only, but it is cheap on battery usage and performance.

`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is more accurate since it access GPS  and provides you the  latitude and longitude information, but it consumes more resources.

So if you want to get  latitude and longitude information more accurately use `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

use permission

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then to get current location

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    ...
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

 //Use Location information from here

     Log.d("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("Latitude","status");
    }
```